# adding an exclusion to a regex

Tags: php, regex

I currently have the following regex to parse data. And an array of "exclusions"

```
$userNameArray = (userName1, user Name2, User Name 3);

$re = '/^(?<timeMined>[0-9]{2}:[0-9]{2}:[0-9]{2}) # timeMined 
     \s+
     (?<userName>[\w\s]+)        # user name
     \s+(?:has\s+looted)\s+    # garbage text between name and amount
     (?<amount>\d+)              # amount
     \s+x\s+                     # multiplication symbol
     (?<item>.*?)\s*$            # item name (to end of line)
   /xmu';
preg_match_all($re, $sample, $matches, PREG_SET_ORDER);
foreach ($matches as $value){
    code
}
```

My code currently has an if statement that if `$value['userName']` is in `$userNameArray` to execute part of a code, and if not, do a different part. However this would be significantly easier if I could just parse the bad users out in the regex.

Comment: Leave that out to your application, don't put it in the regex. This is not significantly easier btw. If you would share of your code, your actual problem might become visible and one might give you better suggestions then to encode the usernames into the regex pattern. What you have here sounds like a standard filter operation that you should keep out of the string parsing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

While you could use a [negative lookahead](http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html) as in

```
$re = '/^(?<timeMined>[0-9]{2}:[0-9]{2}:[0-9]{2}) # timeMined 
     \s+
     (?!user1|user2|user3)       # exclude users <--
     (?<userName>[\w\s]+)        # user name
     \s+(?:has\s+looted)\s+    # garbage text between name and amount
     (?<amount>\d+)              # amount
     \s+x\s+                     # multiplication symbol
     (?<item>.*?)\s*$            # item name (to end of line)
   /xmu';
```

that would encode significant application logic into a regular expression. Most likely, your current solution is easier to understand, more readable, and easier to change.

Comment: that hardcodes the users in correct? It doesn't pull them out of the array.